# Unable to find header file

Tags: linux, header-files

I intend to include `net/ip6_checksum.h` in my code, but the compilation fails because the file is not found.

Searching for the file on the system shows:

```
$ find /usr -name ip6_checksum.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-52/include/net/ip6_checksum.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-54/include/net/ip6_checksum.h
```

The makefile looks for headers under `/usr/lib`

How do I include the file in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Can I 'install' the ip6_checksum.h file in the '/usr/include' path so the solution becomes generic regardless of where the code is compiled?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `-I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-54/include` to your compilation command.

Comment: Is it normal for a header to be in a path other than '/usr/include'? In any case, assuming the code could be compiled on other systems as well, is it safe to expect that the above path of 'ip6_checksum.h' be present on them?

Comment: I added -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-54/include to the compilation code, and now it complains that the other headers ip6_checksum.h is dependant on cannot be found. How do we resolve this?

Comment: Add more -I rules for wherever the dependencies are, I suppose.